# I want to sort a file containing 150 lines of badge numbers , last names, first names, addresses, etc. alphabetically based on the last name.e

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have a file list containing 150 lines, each line contains 14 comma separated strings : badge number ,last name, first name ,etc. When I add a new name to the list I want to re- arrange the lines alphabetically by last name. Here is what I have so far.

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string[]> member = new List<string[]>();
    string[] listofmembers = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\sirslist\\data.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < listofmembers.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] item = listofmembers[i].Split();
        member.Add(item);
    }
}
```

My code so far creates members as follows:

```
member[0][0] = badge1,last name1,address1,etc,
member[1][0] = badge2,last name2,address2,etc
member[2][0] = badge3,last name3,address3,etc
```

I can't figure out how to set this up to look something like

```
member[0][0] = badge number
member[0][1] = last name
member[0][2] = first name
```

so the list can be sorted by member[0][1], member[1][1], member[2][1] etc.

Comment: Your data sounds like a CSV file so I suggest using a CSV parser - CsvHelper can be a nice option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the argument in `.Split()`. To split by comma, you need something like this:

```
List<string[]> member = new List<string[]>();

string[] members = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\sirslist\\data.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < members.Length; i++)
{
    string[] item = members[i].Split(','); // add the argument to .Split()
    member.Add(item);
}
```

You can then use the following for sorting the `members` list:

```
List<string[]> orderedMembers = members
    .OrderBy(m => m[1])
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Forgetting the argument in split was an oversight. I had to go over your answer a few times before I saw your correction which solved that part of my problem .   I want to send the sorted list to a listbox and then write it to a file but all I get in the listbox is the word Collection. If you have a suggestion on how to fix this fine, otherwise I'll just post it as another question. I'm new to Lists and collections so this problem is beyond my paygrade.

Comment: You are probably passing not the string value but an object/array of type Collection`1, represented in the ListBox as myCollection.GetType().ToString() - the default behavior on WinForms as far as I remember. To fully understand your context, please create a separate question with a separate code example.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work (unless you have normal csv with quotes):

```
File.WriteAllLines
(
  ...,
  File.ReadAllLines(...)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Split({','})[1], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
  ...
)
```

Comment: `ReadAllLines` -> `ReadLines`

Comment: @GuruStron, to sort lines you need them all in memory anyway.

Comment: Yeah, fair point. But I'm afraid LINQ does not do in-place sorting, so extra allocations still will be there (but maybe less). Also you can do `.OrderBy(s => s.Split({','})[1], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.